# So I can't do gameObject.AddComponent(StringVariable); anymore... What's the alternative?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Been searching the web, and haven't really gotten a straight answer. What I want to do is this:

```
class Weapon1 
{
   public string Ability = "example";
}

class Weapon2 
{
   public string Ability = "other";
}

class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
  Weapon1 foo = new weapon1();
  Weapon2 boo = new weapon2();
  void useAbility () 
  {
     gameObject.AddComponent(foo.Ability);
     gameObject.AddComponent(boo.Ability);
  }
}
```

But it tells me it's outdated. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use types now. See if this works:

```
class Weapon1 
{
   public Type Ability = typeof(ExampleAbilityClassName);
}

class Weapon2 
{
   public Type Ability = typeof(OtherAbilityClassName);
}

 class Character : MonoBehaviour
 {
    Weapon1 foo = new weapon1();
    Weapon2 boo = new weapon2();
    void useAbility () 
    {
       gameObject.AddComponent(foo.Ability);
       gameObject.AddComponent(boo.Ability);
    }
  }
```

This is anyway much better code than to use strings. Strings are a bit more error prone.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. Just to be clear, I didn't seem to get the var Type unless I said using System, instead of using System.Collections so just a heads up for anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Use the generic version to add a component.

```
i.e gameObject.AddComponent<Ability>();
```

But you will need to convert Ability to be a class.

I would suggest creating all your abilities as sub-classes of Ability.

then explicitly add the ability by name...

```
i.e gameObject.AddComponent<AbilityInvisible>();
i.e gameObject.AddComponent<AbilityInstaGib>();
```

But you will no longer be able to add abilities dynamically by a name string.

To get around this, you could use interfaces, so make your Ability implement the IAbility interface.

Then you can inject the interface into a method to add the ability to your gameObject...

i.e

```
public void UseAbility(IAbility ability)
{
  gameObject.AddComponent(ability);
}
```

to call this, you would just pass in the ability name...

```
AddAbility(AbilityInvisible);
```

Comment: So what you're telling me is if I do something like `AddAbility("String");` it would work? If not, I assume I could do: `Invisible Ability = new Invisible();` and then `AddAbility(Ability);` and it would add the Invisible class? I'm going to test it right now, but I just wanted to respond quickly to see if I understood it (because it might take me a little while to code it in).

Comment: Yes, you could try that too :)

Comment: I get `Argument #1 cannot convert IAbility expression to type System.Type.` IAbility is a class that extends MonoBehaviour. Um I get that when creating the function example you provided. I will of course change all the names when it works, but the class/function name was just so I could make a quick readable thing.

Comment: IAbility is not a class, its an interface. Your Ability base class needs to implement it. If you don't understand C# interfaces you'll need to read up on them first.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Weapon1 : MonoBehvaiour
{
}

class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    void useAbility()
    {
        gameObject.AddComponent<Weapon1>();
    }
}
```